# Анкета JS (null, пустая строка)

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, как синтаксически правильно записать код, чтобы на пустую строку в анкете или на кнопки ок/отмена появлялось доп окно с просьбой ввести еще раз данные?
У меня получается на одну из кнопок не реагирует, в результате null выдает.

```js
var surname = prompt('Введите вашу фамилию:');
while ((surname === " ") || (surname === null)) {
  surname = prompt('Введите корректно вашу фамилию:');
  if ((surname !== " ") && (surname !== null))
    break;
}
```

Спасибо.

Comment: пустая строка и строка состоящая из пробела - разные вещи

Comment: да, вы правы, в этом ошибка

Answer (score 1):

> как синтаксически правильно записать код, чтобы на пустую строку в анкете или на кнопки ок/отмена появлялось доп окно с просьбой ввести еще раз данные?

Предложу вот такой вариант...

```js
let surname 
let mes = 'Введите вашу фамилию:';
do  {
  surname = prompt(mes);
  if (surname === null) break
  mes = 'Введите корректно вашу фамилию:'
} while (!surname.trim())
console.log(surname)
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: единственное, на отмену срабатывает null при выполнении кода

Comment: @Yar777, я специально так сделал. Ведь "Отмена" - есть отмена. Т.е. отказ от ввода этих данных.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо.